# How to use the build cause in build name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I trigger a job remotely using the API the job on jenkins say: "Started by remote host IP". But my jobs can trigger for different reasons and from different sources so it would be great if I in Jenkins could look at a job and directly see the trigger reason.

I know I could pass a string parameter and then in each job view the parameters - but that's not very visible. I would like to preferably see it already in the list of all jobs. Something like: `Reason: X Source: N`.

Is there any way to do this ?

I have noticed that our release jobs take a version parameter that shows like I want - but I don't want to abuse that since these runs are not releases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Build Name

I think you want to set the build name to a different one like here:

[image]

So you can use the [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) and use the build step **Update build name**.

For your case you can use:

```
#${BUILD_NUMBER} ${BUILD_CAUSE}
```

### Cause Badge

Have a look on [Build Trigger Badge Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Trigger+Badge+Plugin), it represents with an icon the reason of the build.

[image]

### Extract the job cause

One possibility to extract the job cause is to use groovy, currentBuild is injected into the runtime and includes information about the causes and so on.

This prints the first (!) cause:

```
println ("Cause: " + currentBuild.causes[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, "Build Name Setter" plugin  works - I used the `${ENV, var="VARIABLENAME"}` syntax to rename the build based on my input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even with the Build Trigger Badge Plugin activated  `http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/api/xml` doesn't show the trigger cause.

You could parse the job's HTML for:

```
<div class="middle-align build-badge" style="width: 100%;">
  <img width="16" height="16" src="/plugin/buildtriggerbadge/images/user-cause.png"
    alt="Trigger UserIdCause : Started by user YourUser" title="Started by user YourUser">
</div>
```

See also the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin):

> This plugin also exposes the cause of the current build as an environment variable.

Comment: As of now I don't need it exposed in the api - and the badge plugin does not seem to handle arbitrary strings.