# Jenkins: How can I know if an automatic process or a user has triggered a build?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there an environment variable in Jenkins which tells me if the build has been ran manually or automatically triggered by polling?

My pipeline works like a charm if automatically triggered, but if manually ran... it always fails, so I think I'm going to edit the pipeline to check how the build has been triggered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately variable `env.BUILD_CAUSE` is not set in Pipeline builds.
For pipeline jobs see following example

```
if ( currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()[0].toString().contains('UserIdCause') ){
    // do steps for manual trigger here
}
```

Other possible causes to compare can be found [here](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Cause.html).

Comment: If this is included in a SCM jenkinsfile, this following error occurs. Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild. This is related to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28178. 

Do you have any suggestion for a workaround or alternative way to derive the cause?

Comment: This article https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/ explains what to do in this situation. You would need to approve the method call as an admin.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I have indeed done that. However that action results in a nasty warning in Jenkins. It labels this as a security vulnerability. "Signatures already approved which may have introduced a security vulnerability (recommend clearing)". That's why I was hoping there may be a different way to derive this value.

Comment: @MattR I believe the only other option is to wrap this in a plugin (pretty small/easy) and then just expose that as its own method to the pipeline. There is probably some plugin that extends available build info in this way too im sure.

Comment: `currentBuild.getBuildCauses().toString().contains('UserIdCause')`
(without the need to approve the method call)

Answer (score 3):

The ability to get causes for a workflow run was released in version 2.22 (2018 Nov 02) to the Pipeline Supporting APIs Plugin. The feature was requested in JENKINS-41272.

A couple methods were added to the currentBuild global variable with that release:

```
getBuildCauses

    Returns a JSON array of build causes for the current build

EXPERIMENTAL - MAY CHANGE getBuildCauses(String causeClass)

    Takes a string representing the fully qualified Cause class and returns a JSON array of build causes filtered by that type for the current build, or an empty JSON array if no causes of the specified type apply to the current build
```

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53342374/5955565.
I have copy-pasted it here because this question is shown first in search results (unlike [How to differentiate build triggers in Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597803/how-to-differentiate-build-triggers-in-jenkins-pipeline/43602399)).

See also `${YOUR_JENKINS_URL}/pipeline-syntax/globals` for a complete, and up to date, list of properties available on currentBuild.