# Jenkins RejectedAccessException in whitelisted method

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins 2.46.3 I'm trying to get the cause of the build (ie whether it was started by a git trigger or a human clicking "build now").  In an answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597803/how-to-differentiate-build-triggers-in-jenkins-pipeline/53342374?noredirect=1#comment98101681_53342374) it is suggested that `${currentBuild.buildCauses}` has that information, and that the method is [whitelisted](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/d0898011f1f2fd9344f0622f6d21e677b97c12e0/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java#L139-L140).  But when I try it, i get a RejectedAccessException :

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getBuildCauses
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:7)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: My guess would be that the plugin either isn't installed or the version isn't up-to-date. Jenkins gives terrible error messages (at least last time I used it) whn calling methods that don't exist or given the wrong type. What version of the `workflow-support-plugin` are you using?

Comment: From the Manifest file, it's 2.11 - but I can't find it in the plugins interface?