# How to define trigger source in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, jenkins-groovy

My Jenkinsfile is built from several stages and can be triggered by the scheduler or via push to Gitlab. I would like to use the trigger source in order to skip several stages for a trigger. How can I identify which event triggered the job?

Comment: You might find this answer helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43609466/5603509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean Push/Merge events, you can check `env.gitlabActionType` [variable](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables).