# How to get build trigger type and working copy status (updated or no change) in Jenkins Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

[image]

Hi, I'm a Jenkins noob here, may I ask if there is a way for me to get the build trigger type (manual or auto) of the current build and the update status of the working copy like in the image above (no change or there are commits) in the Groovy script, so Jenkins can skip the auto build if there is no change?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following groovy snippet to get the number changes.

```
if(currentBuild.changeSets.size() > 0) {
// Chnages are present
}
```

As MB mentioned you can do `currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')` to get manual triggers.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple good answers to your first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43597803/3730626). One suggestion is to use:

```
currentBuild.getBuildCauses(<cause>)
```

Another is to use

```
triggeredBy cause: '<cause>'
```

As for the number of commits, you could simply use git commands to get the number of commits between the existing, checked out repo and the repo in the remote, or you could do it via Jenkins. [Here](https://gist.github.com/halfb00t/3522e7794381a8f3e02146356fad094c) is a gist that should be able to help.